# Safari crash on iOS 9.2.1

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, crash

[Iphone 6s is what I am using]

I have already tried everything on [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192379/safari-on-ios-crashes-whenever-i-try-to-type-anything-into-the-search-field) threat and nothing worked. Its the same problem, I open safari and whenever I try to click on the search bar on the top of the screen, the app crashes and send me back to the homepage. I am using google search engine and I have suggested search turned on and I have tried the following:

Clearing history

changing browsers

Checking for battery saving mode

tried without suggested search

restarted my iphone

None worked.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue. I turned off the "Search Engine Suggestion" and the "Safari Suggestions" in Settings under Safari. Try and see if that works.. It worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting how this seems to be affecting everybody at the same time. Just happened to me, too. Was fine 12 hours ago. Turning off spotlight suggestions fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The above did help temporarily however when tried switching Safari Suggestions etc back on same problem continued.

Try Settings> Safari> Advanced> Website Data> Clear all.  Once this was done I went back and turned everything else back on and Safari stopped crashing and I was able to use it as normal again.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be a problem these days. Did you also disable "spotlight suggestions" in Safari settings?  EDIT: Maybe a reset will do?